# Set the Height of View to Make It Square By Knowing Only Its Width Weight

Tags: android

I have this scenario:
A horizontal LinearLayout that fills the container and `weightSum=100`, and two views inside with weight of 50 each.

Now how do I make these two views square (e.g. the height must be equal to their width). The number of LinearLayout rows is unknown, so basically, I can not wrap them in a vertical container with weights in this case.

Comment: Are you creating these layout programatically or through the interface builder?

Comment: Through Eclipse's XML editor.

Answer (score 1):

> Now how do I make these two views square (e.g. the height must be
>   equal to their width).

If you have just those two views in the `LinearLayout` you have two options:

1. Don't set your layout file directly as the content view, instead inflate it so you have a reference to the root from that file. Then post a `Runnable` on that root view, calculate the desired height and set it back to each of the two children of the `LinearLayout` that wraps them:

   ```
   final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
           R.layout.views_specialheight, null);
   v.post(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           setupHeight((ViewGroup) v);
       }
   });
   setContentView(v);
   ```

   where `setupHeight()` is the method:

   ```
   private void setupHeight(ViewGroup vg) {
       int count = vg.getChildCount();
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           final View v = vg.getChildAt(i);            
           if (v instanceof LinearLayout) {
               int width = v.getWidth();
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
               View one = ((LinearLayout) v).getChildAt(0);
               lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) one.getLayoutParams();
               lp.height = width / 2;
               one.setLayoutParams(lp);
               View two = ((LinearLayout) v).getChildAt(1);
               lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) two.getLayoutParams();
               lp.height = width / 2;
               two.setLayoutParams(lp);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   This method will work pretty well if you just have a wrapper `ViewGroup` subclass that wraps those `LinearLayout` rows. It can(and should) be improved, but I'm sure you get the point.
2. The second option is to use a custom `ViewGroup`(this may be used depending on what you were planing to do with the `LinearLayout`) instead of the `LinearLayout` like this:

   ```
   <com.luksprog.oat.views.SpecialHeightViewGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#0077cc"
          android:text="Button" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="#99cc00"
          android:text="Button" />
   </com.luksprog.oat.views.SpecialHeightViewGroup>
   ```

The `SpecialHeightViewGroup` is a class like this:

```
class SpecialHeightViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

public SpecialHeightViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SpecialHeightViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SpecialHeightViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
            || widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        measureChildren(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize / 2,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                widthSize / 2, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        measureChildren(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize / 2,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                widthSize / 2, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, widthSize / 2);
    } else {
        widthSize = 800; // we don't have restrictions, make it as big as we want
        measureChildren(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize / 2,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                widthSize / 2, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        measureChildren(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize / 2,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                widthSize / 2, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, 400);
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {      
    View one = getChildAt(0);
    one.layout(0, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
    View two = getChildAt(1);
    two.layout(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());     
}

}
```

The custom class isn't properly tested so it may have bugs(it's just an example).

Offtopic: Are you trying by any chance to create an UI like on the new Windows phones(with the tiles thing)?

Comment: Yes, I am creating to recreate the Nokia Lumia UI. For example: http://i.imgur.com/Lw85o.jpg
I never imagined it would be that much complex to create something as simple as a bunch of rows with squares in them in Android.

Comment: @ColorWP.com The first method is not that complex, but in the end it all depends on how you work with those rows. You may want to look at the `GridLayout` also.