# Full-screen tabular layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 12 basically identical views which I want to arrange in a grid that covers the whole screen. Depending on the device's orientation, I want to use a 3x4 or a 4x3 grid.

As far as I understand, there are basically three approaches to this topic:

1. Use a `GridView`
2. Use nested `LinearLayout` instances
3. Use a `TableLayout`

I'd like to have a layout that

1. automatically adapts to orientation changes (as `GridView` does)
2. uses all available screen space (as nested `LinearLayout` instances do)
3. doesn't allow scrolling (and without that "can't scroll any further" effect of the `GridView`)
4. allows me to force the same size on all of my items

By default, `GridView` has scrolling and doesn't fill the screen, whereas `LinearLayout` and `TableLayout` don't automatically adapt to orientation changes.

Currently I'm using a `GridView` with [disabled scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852867/how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling-in-android) and a [custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11101422/857390) which sets the item views' minimum height depending on the orientation and the container's height to force a filled screen. This works but feels like a really ugly hack.

Dynamically constructing nested `LinearLayout` instances depending on the orientation would probably also work, although I haven't tried that.

This seems to be a frequent goal ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067449/android-how-to-stretch-rows-in-the-gridview-to-fill-screen), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690144/how-can-i-force-a-gridview-to-use-the-whole-screen-regardless-of-display-size?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310606/make-full-screen-grid-on-android), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697681/android-gridview-adjusting-to-screen-size)), but all the suggested solutions are either as hackish as mine or don't satisfy some of my requirements.

As I'm new to Android development I'm not sure whether I'm missing something.

**What is the optimal way of implementing this?**

I'm targeting API level 8 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use a GridView

A `GridView` is a widget that you would use when you want to show data in a grid like manner with a larger set of data(as the `GridView`'s recycling mechanism would provide a greater performance than a normal built hierarchy). This is not your case as you want all the views visible from the start and from my point of view the overhead of a `GridView` isn't simply worth it.

> Use nested LinearLayout instances

A good option but avoid nested weights. You could use instead two `LinearLayout` with weights on the longest direction(vertical for portrait and horizontal for landscape) placed in a `RelativeLayout` with a centered anchor view.

> Use a TableLayout

Another option. Use the `stretchColumns` option for the width and `weight` on the `TableRows` for the height.

> Depending on the device's orientation, I want to use a 3x4 or a 4x3
>   grid. What is the optimal way of implementing this?

There isn't an optimal way, either of the solutions above could be used, you could also  [make your own layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512773/set-the-height-of-view-to-make-it-square-by-knowing-only-its-width-weight).

Comment: Thanks for your input. In the end I ended up writing my own layout manager. I'm switching between landscape and portrait orientation using orientation-specific layout XML files.